# Is single quotes (‘) and double quotes (") the same In DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

I execute the following code in GUI,

```
 bigarray(symbol,0,10000000).append!(take('a',100000))
```

The result is displayed as bellow,

```
2019-03-14T14:43:23.375: execution was completed with exception
Failed to append data
```

Then I change the single quotes to double quotes as bellow,

```
bigarray(symbol,0,10000000).append!(take("a",100000))
```

The result is OK.

I remember that the single quotes (‘) and double quotes (") is the same in DolphinDB,

why does DolphinDB report an exception when executing this code?

Answer (score 1):

In DolphinDB, double quotes(") is used to represent a string object. However, the semantics of a single quote depends. If it quotes a single character, the quoted character is viewed as a character. If it quotes more than one character, the quoted object is seen as a string object.